# Can I make a fixed navigation section in an excel spreadsheet that remains constant across other worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Just wondering - I have Column A for a navigation bar if you like, it has a list of links in it.

The only problem, is that with the same list over different worksheets, it varies in size due to how the rows are bigger or smaller based on content elsewhere.

Is there any way to have one fixed size nav bar down the left without massive amounts of fiddling?

Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the rows will increase in size if you fill a cell in column B that contains more info than in Column A - that is if you want to see all the information in Column B and not just limit it to the size of Column A.

Have you thought about inserting a Form? It could have buttons that you click to go to another sheet, and could be present in every sheet. Or place a home button in every sheet that takes you back to the one with the form in.

[A starter on buttons](http://www.contextures.com/excel-vba-worksheet-macro-buttons.html)

Just a thought.

Michael.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - that link doesn't seem to work?

I'll check it out, that makes sense I suppose - so it would just sit over the top of the form proper?

Comment: Hi. I've updated the hyperlink. It points to an example of how buttons would work. I've not set-up a Form with navigation buttons before, but I thought it might be a possibility. Although it could be more complicated than I expected.

Comment: Thanks! Just had a quick read but stopped when I saw 'Macros' - our work systems don't allow macros to be run. :(